# JFrame Exit on close does not appear in java

Tags: java, swing

Take the example from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html), there are some examples in your [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/TranslucentWindowDemoProject/src/misc/TranslucentWindowDemo.java).

My idea is the following:

[image]

I have achieved that my application has a transparent background, but the minimize and close application buttons do not appear

This is my code:

**main**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.awt.GraphicsDevice.WindowTranslucency.*;

public class Textmovie extends JFrame {

    /*
    public Textmovie() {
        //setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame jf = new JFrame("");
       jf.setUndecorated(true);
       jf.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,10));
       //jf.setOpacity(0.55f);
       jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       jf.add(new texscroll());
       jf.setSize(720,480);
       jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Part 2**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 *
 * @author inide
 */
public class texscroll extends JPanel {
    int  x =510 , y = 25;

    public texscroll() {
        setOpaque(false);
    }


    @Override

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

        Font font = new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN,15);
        g2.setFont(font);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        String string = "stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow";

        g2.drawString(string ,x,y);
        try{Thread.sleep(14);}
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        };
        x-=1;

            if(x==-10*string.length()){
              x= 510;  
            }
        repaint();

       // System.out.println(string.length()  );
    }
}
```

And this is shown when running in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2

[image]

**They can explain to me what I have to do to make the buttons appear (minimize and close application).**

Comment: `try{Thread.sleep(14);}` instead paint? Really

Comment: *"They can explain to me what I have to do to make the buttons appear (minimize and close application)."* - When using the native look and feel, you can't

Comment: @MadProgrammer But the examples found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html they work and their funds are transparent

Comment: @MadProgrammer I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330245/how-to-create-background-of-jframe-transparent-in-java-but-keeping-buttons, you can explain to me what I should modify in my code

Comment: I’ve never been able to get the examples from the tutorials to work - but the screen shot is using metal (i think)

Comment: I had it I my head that the look and feel had to provide the frame decorations before you could make transparent frame with frame decorations, but it turns out that it's simply not possible at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually dig into the code based on the exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Frame.java:989)
```

You'll find that it's impossible to make a frame transparent AND be decorated...

```
@Override
public void setBackground(Color bgColor) {
    synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
        if ((bgColor != null) && (bgColor.getAlpha() < 255) && !isUndecorated()) {
            throw new IllegalComponentStateException("The frame is decorated");
        }
        super.setBackground(bgColor);
    }
}
```

The fact that the tutorials show it working is irrelevant and an error on the part of the tutorials.

It "might" have been possible in earlier "unreleased" versions of the API (using `AWTUtilities`), but it simply no longer possible

Now, we've got that out the way, this, inside `paint`...

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(14);
} catch (Exception ex) {
};
x -= 1;

if (x == -10 * string.length()) {
    x = 510;
}
repaint();
```

is not how you do animation in Swing

This is just going to cause you no end of issues, as nothing is committed to the native peer until AFTER the `paintComponent` exist (this is how double buffering works)

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

A more appropriate solution might look something like...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Textmovie extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Textmovie();
    }

    public Textmovie() throws HeadlessException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jf = new JFrame("");
                jf.setUndecorated(true);
                jf.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 10));
                //jf.setOpacity(0.55f);
                jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jf.add(new texscroll());
                jf.pack();
                jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                jf.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class texscroll extends JPanel {

        private int x = 510, y = 25;

        private String string = "stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow";

        public texscroll() {
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD + Font.PLAIN, 15);
            setFont(font); 
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);

            setOpaque(false);
            Timer timer = new Timer(14, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    x -= 1;

                    if (x == -10 * string.length()) {
                        x = 510;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(720, 480);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.drawString(string, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Friend all in one document, no longer divided into two parts?

Answer (score 0):

```
jf.setUndecorated(true);
```

makes the title bar invisible and that includes the minimize and close buttons so you should remove that line (because it's false by default)

Comment: If I delete that line, the application will no longer run :( and I would lose the transparent background color

Comment: try to not removing  jf.setUndecorated(true); and inserting this after the background (that i supose you do)  jf.setUndecorated(false);

Comment: if that doesn't work try doing the transparent background with this: https://www.pushing-pixels.org/2008/02/27/translucent-and-shaped-windows-in-core-java.html

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you’re calling `jf.setUndecorated(true)`. This method removes the the title bar, which contains the minimize and maximize buttons.

Unfortunately, the window have to be undecorated to have a system title bar, but the look and feel can provide a title bar. To enable it, you have to call this before your frame is made visible:

```
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Comment: If I delete that line, the application will no longer run :( and I would lose the transparent background color

Comment: @Kary you don’t have to remove it, you should just add my last line

Comment: it does not work either friend do not appear the buttons :(

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330245/how-to-create-background-of-jframe-transparent-in-java-but-keeping-buttons, you can explain to me what I should modify in my code

Comment: And if you replace setUndecorated with my last line?